# Vim yank path under the cursor

Tags: vim

What's the most efficient way to yank a path that's under a cursor? So if a line has the following contents:

```
/some/file /some/other/file /last/file
```

... and the cursor is over `other`, I would like to yank `/some/other/file`. Normally, if it were a word `yiw` would work, but since that path contains quotes, `yiw` would only yank `other` rather than the entire `/some/other/file`.

Is there a way to efficiently yank the entire filename?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A **w**ord consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>   sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
>   tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
>   is also considered to be a word.
>
> A **W**ORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
>   space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.

`yiW` - just need to capitalize the W

Answer (score 0):

`Byt<space>`: 
`B` to go to the start of the file location,
`yt<space>` to yank up to the next line space.

Answer (score 0):

While I would use `yiW` as in dave's answer, `ByE` (go to beginning of WORD, yank to end of WORD) is another possibility.